# Django + AWS s3 can upload files but not access them

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, python-django-storages

Following [this tutorial](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/08/01/how-to-setup-amazon-s3-in-a-django-project.html) I set up our system to use Amazons S3 file storage using boto3 and Django-storages. I ran the `collectstatic` command and it worked just fine, the files show up in the AWS Management Console. But when running the server locally (`runserver`) all static files are missing. Looking at the console there are the error messages

```
GET https://BUCKET.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/static/admin/css/nav_sidebar.css net::ERR_ABORTED 403 (Forbidden)
```

for each of the files. The url looks right to me, the upload worked fine, but apparently the access doesn't work. Does this have something to do with my config in AWS? Or is this a Django settings issue?

The settings file looks like this:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = []
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'XYZ'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'XYZ'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'BUCKET'
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '%s.s3.amazonaws.com' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME

AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {
    'CacheControl': 'max-age=86400',
}

AWS_STATIC_LOCATION = 'static'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'hq.storage_backends.StaticStorage'
STATIC_URL = "https://%s/%s/" % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, AWS_STATIC_LOCATION)

AWS_MEDIA_LOCATION = 'media'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'hq.storage_backends.MediaStorage'
```

Comment: make sure the bucket policy is public (and files are publicly accessible), if it is you might try to run `runserver --insecure`, don't use it in production though obviously
if files are not publicly accessible you might try setting `AWS_DEFAULT_ACL='public-read'` and run collect static again to make them public

Comment: Block all public access was on, I turned it off for now. How was I able to upload something if access is blocked?

Comment: you use the credentials to the bucket, so that gives you an ability to post images to the bucket, but since the default policy is not publicly accessible it's not being returned when requested without credentials, however as it's static data it's probably a good idea to make it public, or either you might want to setup aws to allow only your specific domain for that bucket

Answer (score 7, accepted):

make sure the bucket policy is public (and files are publicly accessible), if it is you might try to run runserver --insecure, don't use it in production though obviously if files are not publicly accessible you might try setting `AWS_DEFAULT_ACL='public-read'` and run collect static again to make them public

I'd suggest using environ to alter this settings something like

```
import environ

...

AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = env('AWS_DEFAULT_ACL')
```

in your settings.py or where ever you store the settings to s3 bucket
And use env vars to alter that upon need

So after installing and setting up `environ` you can easily change that using env variables be simply setting `AWS_DEFAULT_ACL` to `public-read`
like `export AWS_DEFAULT_ACL=public-read`

Comment: This command did it! Thank you very much it seems to work flawlessly now!